# installutil.exe is not a valid win32 application

Tags: win32-process, installutil

When I try to install service using Installutil.exe I receive a message c:\windows\Microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\Installutil.exe is not a valid Win32 application.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I found out that for some reason the InstallUtil got corrupted during installation and got 0 byte size. So replacing that executable with correct size one - should fix the issue.

[image]

Comment: referenced...http://ilanas.blogspot.ca/2007/02/net-wtf-installutilexe-gets-corrupted.html

Comment: Used web installer to install .NET framework 4.5.1 and got this too. I wonder why?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.
As I'm on 64 bit OS,
I used the "Framework64" directory instead of the "Framework" directory, I used C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ installutil.exe
and then it work.

Answer (score 0):

This also happens if the service binary is built as a DLL instead of a Windows Application (.dll instead of .exe)